# Prolog Printing a Tree

Tags: tree, prolog, binary-tree

```
printtree_3( bt(Label,[],[]) ).
printtree_3( bt(Label,Left,Right) ) :- 
    printtree_3( Left ), 
    printtree_3( Right ), 
    printlabel( Label ).

printlabel( X ) :- write( X ), write( ' ' ).
```

I am attempting to traverse a tree for the first time in prolog and I thought I would do so by printing a tree with someone else's code to see it work in person. The problem is that trying to run this code I always get "False" by the swipl compiler.

For example.

```
?- printtree_3(a(b,c,d)).
```

returns false instead of printing the tree. I think that my predicate call is wrong, but I'm not sure. Again I take no credit for the provided code, I just want to run it so I can experiment. If anyone can explain why it's not working I would be very thankful.

Comment: Hey guys, I have now tried to call the predicate with printtree_3(bt(a,b,c)). But with no success. I may have missed the point. Can someone just give me what a valid call would look like.

Answer (score 1):

This fails (returns "false") because the query is false:

You are asking

```
printtree_3(a(b,c,d))
```

giving a tree with the functor `a`

However the code only defines clauses for predicate `printtree_3` that accept an argument with functor `bt` (probably "binary tree" more than "beached thing"):

```
printtree_3( bt(Label,[],[])      )
printtree_3( bt(Label,Left,Right) )
```

There is nothing that matches your query. Prolog says "false" (which means there is no evidence that `printtree_3(a(b,c,d))` is true)

Comment: @GuyCoder difficult because the goal of imperative-code tychk is to ensure that a function is ever only called with args from a certain domain. In Prolog, these args may be uninstantiated vars, and calling with args from a wrong domain may actually be completely accceptable (yielding, of course, `false`). Typeless Clojure has [specs](https://clojure.org/guides/spec), which sounds like sth good. (Btw Lambda-Prolog has some ML-style type expressions, but [adding types to LP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/types-logic-programming) seems to have been not met which much success. Maybe in Mercury?)

Comment: `adding types to LP seems to have been not met which much success` I use to think types should be added to Prolog, but now don't think they should. However some allow the `any` type which lets all pass and yet is still a type. Personally I am gaining enough experience to know when and when not to add type checks and just as importantly when to remove them after they have served their purpose.

Comment: Hey guys I  tried to ask printtree_3(bt(a,b,c)). And I'm still not getting anything, can anyone explain why?

Comment: @JunDeveloper Because the next call will be `printtree_3(b)`, which also does not match anything. You are going too fast, you need to read a Prolog intro text. "Hasten slowly".